# VBA Excel 2010 dictionary object required error

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I'm trying to write code that looks at an array "arr", then loops through each value in that array to compare to a newly created dictionary. If the key already exists, the value (count) of the key is supposed to be incremented by 1, otherwise the key should be added with a value of 1.

However, the below line is throwing an Object Required error:

> ```
>         If dic.Exists(c.Value) Then ' Runtime Error 424: Object Required
> ```

The entire sub is below:

```
Private Sub PODic()


    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim c As Variant


    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' late bind
        dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
    lrow = lrow - 1
        Debug.Print lrow

    arr = ActiveSheet.Range("d2", ActiveSheet.Cells(lrow, "d")).Value

        For Each c In arr
            Debug.Print c
            If dic.Exists(c.Value) Then ' Runtime Error 424: Object Required
                dic(c.Value) = dic(c.Value) + 1
            Else
                dic.Add c.Value, 1
            End If
        Next

    For Each k In dic
        Debug.Print k & "," & dic(k)
    Next k



    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

    MsgBox "Populate dictionary macro complete."



End Sub
```

I believe this might be something to do with the variable type used for c (or for the dic perhaps) but I can't figure out where the problem is occuring. I also tried solving this by creating an On Error GoTo but had the same issue.

```
         On Error GoTo ERRINCVAL
            dic.Add cell.Value, 1
            On Error GoTo 0



ERRINCVAL:

    dic(c.Value) = dic(c.Value) + 1 ' Same error thrown on this line, if I try to use GoTo instead of If
    Resume Next
```

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not add words such as "Solved" to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c.value` doesn't make sense here. `c` here is an `item` in the `array` so you can directly refer to it.

You should try it like this...

```
For Each c In arr
    Debug.Print c
    If dic.Exists(c) Then
        dic(c) = dic(c) + 1
    Else
        dic.Add c, 1
    End If
Next
```

Or you can use the following approach as well to get the desired output...

```
Dim i As Long
arr = ActiveSheet.Range("d2", ActiveSheet.Cells(lrow, "d")).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    Debug.Print arr(i, 1)
    If dic.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then ' Runtime Error 424: Object Required
        dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
    Else
        dic.Add arr(i, 1), 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Fantastic. That worked perfectly, thank you. So, it looks like the problem was indeed with the For Each c var. I wasn't properly using the array, I think.

Comment: You're welcome! That's right. Actually you can use your method as well (see the edited answer) after removing `.Value`

Comment: @sktneer, you should remove `dic.Exists(c)` and `dic.Add c, 1`. Those lines are useless.

Answer (score 3):

@sktneer has the correct answer.  I just wanted to demonstrate a cleaner way of writing it.

Using a **With** statements makes the code more readable and is more efficient.

There is no reason to have a **Last Row** variable.

> Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value

It is not necessary to use a temporary array variable for use in a **For Each** loop.  The VBA will automatically create one when it initializes the loop.

> For Each Key In .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value

There is no need to test if a **Key** exists and then add the **Key** with value 1 or increment the existing **Key**.  The VBA will automatically create the **Key** it it doesn't exist.

> dic(Key) = dic(Key) + 1

Reuse the same **Key** variable when Adding **Key/Value** pairs or iterating over the **Dictionary**.

> dic.Add Key, 1
>
> For Each Key in dic

You can use **Join** to print all the **Keys** and **Items** to the immediate window.

> Debug.Print "Keys: "; Join(dic.Keys(), ",")
>
> Debug.Print "Items: "; Join(dic.Items(), ",")

```
Private Sub PODic()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim dic As Object, Key As Variant

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Key In .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value
            dic(Key) = dic(Key) + 1
        Next
    End With

    Debug.Print "Keys: "; Join(dic.Keys(), ",")
    Debug.Print "Items: "; Join(dic.Items(), ",")

    For Each Key In dic
        Debug.Print Key & "," & dic(Key)
    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

    MsgBox "Populate dictionary macro complete."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **declare** the dictionary object.

> **We declare a dictionary as follows**:
>
> ```
> Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
> ```
>
> *or*
>
> ```
> Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
> Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
> ```

Lots more information about setting up and using dictionaries in VBA [at this site](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Creating_a_Dictionary).

---

Also as a rule of thumb, use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module (especially when troubleshooting) to make sure your variables and objects are all setup properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I tried both options, I get 'compile error: user-define type not defined', on the dim.

Comment: I would switch to early binding, I'm almost sure that's your only remaining issue.

Comment: `Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

Answer (score 1):

You could use simplified form of assigning value to dictionary:

```
dic("key1") = dic("key1") + 1
```

Comment: or simply `dic("key1") = dic("key1") + 1` given that a missing key returns `Empty` which will be implicitly converted to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Final code ended up:

Private Sub PODic()

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim Counter As Long

Dim lrow As Long
Dim c As Variant

Dim dic As Object
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' late bind
    dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
lrow = lrow
    Debug.Print lrow

Dim i As Long
    arr = ActiveSheet.Range("d2", ActiveSheet.Cells(lrow, "d")).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    Debug.Print arr(i, 1)
    If dic.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
    Else
        dic.Add arr(i, 1), 1
    End If
Next

For Each k In dic
    Debug.Print k & "," & dic(k)
Next k
Debug.Print dic.Count


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

Using c.value implies you're treating it as a range object and accessing its 'value' property -- which your code will let you do as c is declared as variant.

However, what I think you're doing is looping through each element in the array -- in which case you shouldn't use c.value, just c on its own.

I think it would be better to loop through the array using a for-next loop between array's ubound and lbound.

So try:

```
    Dim Index as Long

    For Index = lbound(arr,1) to ubound(arr,1)

If dic.Exists(arr(Index,1)) Then

' Array arr is 1-based but items in dic might be 0-based, so adjust if necessary'

dic(arr(Index-1,1)) = dic(arr(Index-1,1)) + 1
' if dic is not 0-based, get rid of the -1 above.'

Else

dic.Add arr(Index,1), 1

End If

    Next index
```

Untested, written on mobile.

Comment: Many thanks! I ended up doing something almost exactly alike (for i = 1 to ubound(arr,1). When I reference an entry within an array, merely giving arr(i,1) returns the value of the array with those coordinates, right? Whereas  the c.value would only be used for a range? I copied my code from elsewhere without picking up on that difference.

Comment: Yes, coordinates are how you refer to elements in arrays. Depending on array's dimensions and structure of array: arr(X) for 1-dimensional array, arr(X,Y) for 2-dimensional, arr(X,Y,Z) for 3-dimensional, etc. -- and, as you said, .value is for range object.